# Can't load matplotlib 1.3.0

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, package

I'm running Python 2.7.5 on a Windows 7 machine. I've upgraded matplotlib to the latest stable version, 1.3.0, and whenever I try to use it (or start IPython with PyLab), I get the following error:

"matplotlib requires pyreadline >= 1.5.6"

The thing is, I have PyReadline 2.0.1 installed. Any ideas what to do? Thanks!

Comment: if you `import pyreadline` from a python prompt what do you get?  I suspect you have more than one version installed and are running into path issues.

Comment: @tcaswell you can add your comment as an answer...

Comment: @ssantic If you solved please post how you solved it as an answer.

Comment: I uninstalled pyreadline, but for some reason had to manually remove it from my Python installation folder, then installed it again. I also had to downgrade to matplotlib 1.2.1, as I saw a post on the developers forum citing this issue as not uncommon. It will be fixed in version 1.3.1 which is coming soon.